# Does iPod/iPhone 2G supports Multi Tasking and Single-Sign-On?

Tags: iphone, multitasking

I have apple ipod 2G and IOS version 4.1. Does my ipod(2G) supports Multi tasking? Now I am working on face book application and I have implemented latest face book-IOS-SDK Which supports multi tasking and Single-sign-on. Does my ipod(2G) supports Single-sign-on and multi tasking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but no. Only the 3rd generation and fourth generation ipods support multitasking due to a slower processor and restricted memory.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the iPod 2G does not support multi-tasking...

Answer (score 1):

Multitasking (and some other features, like home wallpaper, etc.) are only available on post-2G devices. This is mainly due to memory limitations and the slower CPU.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS_(Apple)#Multitasking